# Sending mail via php, malformed reply-to

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm having to modify our clubs event calendar as we're having problems with gmails spam filter.
I've tried to modify the following code so that the senders email is now the "reply-to" and the from is "calendar@dsac.co.uk" in the hope that using an email from our own domain will solve the spam problem. The mail fails to send and i get this error "Reply-To:  missing or malformed local part (expected word or "<")"

I've tried changing the reply-to email to  but with the same results. I'm learning php as I go and none of this code is mine, I'm just trying to make it work.

Here is the code I've modified.

```
<?php
require('wordpress/wp-load.php');
get_header();
?>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content" role="main">

<?php
include ("inc/functions.inc");
include ("inc/dbconnect.inc");

$db = db_connect();

$cookie = $_COOKIE[User];
$cookiearray = explode(",",$cookie);
if (isset($_POST['to'])){
    $particode = $_POST['IDs'];
    $participants = explode(",",$particode);
    $search = "";
    $numpar = count($participants)-1;
    for ($i=0;$i<=$numpar;$i++){
        if ($search == ""){
            $search = "ID LIKE ".$participants[$i];
        }else {
            $search = $search." OR ID LIKE ".$participants[$i];
        }
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Mail FROM users WHERE ".$search, $db);
    if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $numpar = mysql_num_rows($result)-1;
    for ($i=0;$i<=$numpar;$i++){
        if ($i == 0){
            $to = mysql_result($result,$i,'Mail');
        }else {
            $to = $to.", ".mysql_result($result,$i,'Mail');
        }
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Mail FROM users WHERE ID LIKE ".$cookiearray[0], $db);
    if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $replyto = mysql_result($result,0,'Mail');


    $from = 'calendar@dsac.co.uk';

    $test = mail($to, $subject, $msg,'From: '.$from,'Reply-To: '.$replyto);


    if ($test){
        Echo "<b>Mail sent</b>";
    }else{
        echo "<b>An error has occured trying to send your mail, sorry</b>";
    }
}Else {
    $particode = $_POST['participants'];
    $participants = explode(",",$particode);
    $search = "";
    $numpar = count($participants)-1;
    for ($i=0;$i<=$numpar;$i++){
        if ($search == ""){
            $search = "ID LIKE ".$participants[$i];
        }else {
            $search = $search." OR ID LIKE ".$participants[$i];
        }
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM users WHERE ".$search, $db);
    if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    Echo "<form name='mailform' action='eventmail.php' method='POST'>\n
    <table border='0'>\n
    <tr><td><b>To:</b></td><td><textarea rows='2' cols='45' name='to' readonly>";
    for ($i=0;$i<=$numpar;$i++){
        if ($i == 0){
            echo mysql_result($result,$i,'Name');
        }else {
            echo "; ".mysql_result($result,$i,'Name');
        }
    }
    Echo "</textarea><input type='hidden' name='IDs' value='".$particode."'></td></tr>\n
    <tr><td valign='top'><b>Subject:</b></td><td><input type='text' name='subject' size='45'></td></tr>\n
    <tr><td valign='top'><b>Message:</b></td><td><Textarea name='msg' rows='20' cols='45'></textarea></td></tr>\n
    <tr><td colspan=2 valign='top'><input type='submit' value='Send mail'></td></tr></table>\n
    </form>
    ";
}

?>

</div>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: i tried putting the reply-to email between <> but the same error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using this headers might work.

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: $brand_name <$from>";
$headers[] = "Bcc: Name <name@domain.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>"; 
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "Return-Path: <$from>";
$headers[] = "X-Priority: 3";//1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = Low
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```